How to read master DB table into a Map using flux and spring boo t reactive programming
I am new to reactive programming.
My need is to populate all master data into a Hashmap from master data table at service start.
I am using reactive to get flux of master data as below
The above code doesn't work and my statusMap is always empty.
Flux<StatusMaster> list = statusMasterRepository.findAll();
list.flatMap(status -> {
        statusMap.put(status.getAccountStatus(),status);
        return Flux.just(status);
        });


below doesn't work either
  list.flatMap(typeMaster -> {
        typeMap.put(typeMaster.getRequestType(),typeMaster);
        return Mono.just(typeMaster);
    }).doOnNext(r -> System.out.println("test")).subscribe();


btw, you should not do anything like that in flatMap or map. Use reduce, or just in subscribe in the worst case scenario.

Its fixed.
Issue was not the way I was processing the response, but a bug in R2DBC, where it doesnt consider @Table(name = ).
It picks up the entity name as table name. Changing the entity class name fixed the issue
list.map(requestTypeMaster -> {
        requestTypeMap.put(requestTypeMaster.getRequestType(),requestTypeMaster);
        return requestTypeMaster;
            }).subscribe();

